# Question About Clusters' Architectural Design

Tags: discussion

Can I ask about the architectural design of the clusters? For example can I ask the following:

What is the architectural design of a bare bone cluster (e.g., #of IPs, switches, master(s) and their slave(s)), for using Apache Mesos?

Comment: I'm not native english, so please forgive this followup question. What's the difference between asking this and, for example, asking `could you give me an example of a linux cluster for Apache Mesos`? To me it looks very much like asking for a jump-start tutorial for setting up a MesoSphere, but again `architectural design` might be throwing me off.

Comment: @Reaces Updated the question for clarification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think something like that would likely end up being closed as too broad, whole books have been written on clusters and the like. I could equally see it being closed for 'Hire a Consultant' reasons or 'We don't do free design work' all of which I've seen similar questions closed for.

Having said all that the only real litmus test is to ask the question and see what happens (and if the question is literally what's above then expect downvotes for not showing research et al).

Comment: I would also be inclined to interpret every upvote to this answer as a potential close vote.